# QrCode class not found or interface not found using Endroid/QrCode in Cakephp2.X

Tags: cakephp, qr-code

I'm new in cakePHP and I'm trying to run  Endroid/QrCode in Cakephp2.x with no success. My controller looks like follows:

```
 public function presta_my_function(){



    App::import('Vendor', 'Endroid\QrCode', array('file' => 'Endroid/QrCode/QrCode.php'));
```

in this case I get the following error:
2017-09-27 02:11:55 Error: Fatal Error (1): Interface 'Endroid\QrCode\QrCodeInterface' not found in [C:\MAMP\htdocs\xxxx\app\Vendor\Endroid\QrCode\QrCode.php, line 18].

On the other hand, if try to do an import of QrCodeInterface.php before loading QrCode.php I get the following error:
2017-09-27 02:42:15 Error: Fatal Error (1): Class 'QrCode' not found in [C:\MAMP\htdocs\xxx\app\Controller\ActivitesController.php, line 971].
In this case the code looks like follows:

```
 public function presta_my_space(){


    App::import('Vendor', 'Endroid', array('file' => 'Endroid/QrCode/QrCodeInterface.php'));
    App::import('Vendor', 'Endroid\QrCode', array('file' => 'Endroid/QrCode/QrCode.php'));
```

Endroid\QrCode is installed in /app/vendor/Endroid/QrCode.
Any idea about what is failing?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot include namespaced, composer based libraries like `endroid/QrCode` using `App::import()`, as this will only load a single file. Sure, you could load each and every single file manually, but that's anything but a good idea.

Switch your CakePHP application to using composer (back up your application before fiddling with this), and then ditch `App::import()` and use the library [**as shown in their docs**](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode).

See **[Cookbook > Installation > Advanced Installation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html)**

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. I think the library is properly installed using composer. The problem is I'm getting the same result calling autoload.php file with require_once() in my controller